# Sort 2 dimensional array based on the value in one row

Tags: c#

I have data like

```
1   3   9   2   7   8   9
120 70  76  190 300 50  40
```

how can I sort the array based on the second row and return the value of the max number from the first row. I mean, the output become >

```
7    2    1    9   3   8   9
300  190  120  76  70  50  40
```

And I get the `7` as output.

Comment: @Mark E, I already tried with for loops that  I could get the result but it is not efficient. I am looking for something which is stright forward with less code (something like a method).

Comment: Why you use 2 dimensional array at the first place? With exactly 2 rows? It looks like a candidate for a single dimensional array, don't you think?

Comment: I'd suggest posting the code that you have that works and someone can then look at what can be done to make it more efficient.  Also how are you judging efficiency?

Comment: Do you need the re-arranged table of numbers, or do you want only the specific entry above the maximum in the lower row (`7` in your example)?

Answer (score 1):

First I would get your data out of the rectangular array into something a bit more usable. To do this, first convert the data into a `List<Tuple<int, int>>` because it is much easier to work with.

```
int[,] rawData = { { 1, 3, 9, 2, 7, 8, 9 }, { 120, 70, 76, 190, 300, 50, 40 } };
var data = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

for(int i = 0; i < rawData.GetLength(1); i++)
{
    data.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(rawData[0, i], rawData[1, i]));
}
```

Then it is just a matter of using a Linq query to get the data you want.

```
var result = data.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2).First().Item1;
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EfRj03)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to know the answer to 'what's the max number **now**' (or to put it differently, to keep the order rather then sort it post processing - beware it has a performance penalty!) then `SortedList` may come in handy:

```
        int[] a = { 1, 3, 9, 2, 7, 8, 9 };
        int[] b = { 120, 70, 76, 190, 300, 50, 40 };

        var sortedList = new SortedList<int,int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            sortedList[b[i]] = a[i];        
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sortedList.Last().Value);
```

*(if you want to see what's current max value as you add data just move `WriteLine` to inside of the loop)*